# Sitecore FileUtil.ZipFiles creating empty zip file

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to use the `ZipFiles()` utility method and its producing an empty zip file. I am using Sitecore 6.5. There are no error, permissions or otherwise.

Any thoughts? Here is the code.

```cs
public void CreateZipFile(string zipfileName, List<string> files)
{
var zipfile = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", TempFolder.Folder, "myfolder", zipfileName) ;
var fileArray = files.ToArray();
var x = FileUtil.ZipFiles(zipfile, fileArray);
}
```

EDIT:
I am passing the files like this

```cs
var files = new List<string> { FileUtil.MapPath("/temp/sample.xlf") };
```

Comment: In your `files` list do you pass the absolute path of the file (e.g. `c:\inetpub\readme.text`) or just relative to the web app root?

Comment: I have tried both, currently I am passing var files = new List<string> { FileUtil.MapPath("/temp/sample.xlf") };

Comment: The proper usage is `FileUtil.ZipFiles("/test.zip", new []{"/web.config", "/otherfile.txt"})` and the file will be created in the root of your web app.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I have the same result. An empty 45kb zip file.

Comment: 45kB is a big size for an empty zip. Are you sure that there are no hidden files or directories in the zip?

Comment: I agree, it seemed large for an empty file. Using windows "extract all" it would throw an error about an invalid zip file. Double clicking the zip would open an empty zip. Using to view/extract 7zip it actually has files and worked. Very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper usage of `FileUtil.ZipFiles` method is:

```cs
FileUtil.ZipFiles("/test.zip", new []{"/web.config", "/otherfile.txt"})
```

Sitecore automatically maps paths. The zip file will be created in your web app root.

---

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

If you want to create a zip file outside the web root and with a flat structure inside, you can use Sitecore `ZipWriter` class like this:

```cs
public static string ZipFiles(string absolutePathToZipfile, string[] files)
{
    using (ZipWriter zipWriter = new ZipWriter(absolutePathToZipfile))
    {
        foreach (string path in files)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path.StartsWith("/") ? FileUtil.MapPath(path) : path))
                zipWriter.AddEntry(FileUtil.GetFileName(path), fileStream);
        }
    }
    return absolutePathToZipfile;
}
```

Comment: It seems no matter where the files live or the zip is created the structure within the zip file is based off of the web root. Meaning, all files are in folders within the zip. I really wanted to have the zip files created in the sitecore temp folder and have the files flat in the zip.